# How to get purchase state: InApp Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, state, in-app-billing

Have `InApp Purchase` in my application.

What i need to know is? What is the default value will be there at startup? and What are possible value for InApp?

I have tried like this for getting the state

```
Purchase.getPurchaseState()
```

While im testing in device it throws the value as '0'(purchased). I didn't purchase. Testing only.

Let me know what's wrong with me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549786/handling-in-app-billing-refunds-in-v3

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of the accounts you had on the device had already purchased it. The account that was used to dowload the app from google play is checked, or if the app was sideloaded, the first registered google account is checked to see if a purchase is associated with it.